# como extraer texto en este caso

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Estoy intentando extraer unos caracteres de una web con python usando request.
Me descargo la web haciendo lo siguiente:

```
r = s.get("url")
```

Al resultado  obtenido lo guardo una variable

```
cadena=r.text
```

Esta variable la manejo posteriormente con split. El caso es que en la mayoria de los casos nos encontramos paginas con una estructura tal que asi:

```
<strong>MEDIO: </strong> TVE<br />
```

En ese caso genial, porque para extraer TVE le hago un split haciendo esto:

```
micadena=(cadena.split('>MEDIO: </strong> ')[1])
```

Pero hay otros caso que sale asi

```
<strong>MEDIO: </strong>TV Local <br />
```

Con lo cual no me vale la cadena anterior teniendo que modificarlo por esto:

```
micadena=cadena.split('>MEDIO: </strong>')[1])
```

Claro... si lo programo de la  manera 1,  al encontrarse algo como la manera 2 pues el programa me falla.

Mi pregunta es.. como podria hacer algo generico que me sirviera para ambos casos?
ojo... en alguna web me he encontrado cosas como esta

```
<strong>MEDIO:</strong> TV Madrid <br />
```

La colocacion de los dichosos espacios me esta matando.  Mi intencion es extraer TVE, TV local o TV Madrid, independientemente de como hayan colocado los espacios a la hora de programar la web.
A alguien se le ocurre una solucion?

Comment: y por que no usas una expresion regular?

Comment: el caso es que ademas de TVE TV Local TV Madrid pueden haber infinitos casos.... TV alemania TV italia... etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para estos casos lo mejor es usar expresiones regulares:

```
import re

# Suponiendo los posibles casos que has puesto:
texto = '<strong>MEDIO: </strong> TVE<br /><strong>MEDIO: </strong>TV Local <br /><strong>MEDIO:</strong> TV Madrid <br />'

medios = re.findall('MEDIO:\s?</strong>\s?(\w+\s?\w+)',texto)

print(medios)
```

Esto te devolvería:

```
['TVE', 'TV Local', 'TV Madrid']
```

En primer lugar busca `MEDIO:` seguido de 0 ó 1 espacio (`\s?`) seguido de `</strong>` y otra vez 0 ó 1 espacio. Luego con `(\w+\s?\w+)` captura cualquier caracter o caracteres seguidos de 0 ó 1 espacio y otra vez cualquier caracter o caracteres.

Comment: el caso es que ademas de TVE TV Local  TV Madrid pueden hacer infinitos casos.... TV alemania TV italia... etc etc...

Comment: En esos casos seguiría funcionando, mientras estén formados por dos palabras. Si fuesen más habría que modificarlo un poco.

Comment: Voy a probar a ver.. muchas gracias.

Comment: Lo dicho, me devuelve los 3 a la vez tal y como comentaste,  no lo entendi yo bien.....Realmente lo que  necesito es que me devuelva el medio que se encuentra en esa pagina.  En una de las paginas es TVE......  en otra de las paginas es TV madrid  en otra es TV italia....   es decir... no que me devuelva 3 a la vez... sino que me devuelva el q le corresponde.  Jope que pena!

Comment: Pero, ¿cómo tienes las páginas?¿Todas como texto en una misma variable? si es así, habrá algo que te indique a qué página corresponde cada medio que no has puesto en la pregunta, ¿no?

Comment: Entiendo que tienes en un texto la etiqueta html y luego la parte que pone MEDIO: etc, varias veces, no?

Comment: Nada,  al final lo he resuelto siendo mas estricto en los split  acotando cada vez mas. De un split mas general a otro mas particular.  Pero la idea me la diste tu con lo de "en primer lugar busca medio... seguido de...."... eso me encendio la lucecita a resringir a partir de ahi. Muchisimas gracias!!